# Set the default value for a module field in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I have a module named `Cases` in my `SugarCRM` environment which has several fields like `name`, `id`, `account_name`, `date_created`, `description` and so on, and one custom field named `custom_account_number`.

I want to set its value to the one of the `account_name` field, how can I do that using a custom php script in custom folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Sugar 7.2 , then it is simple,

**1**. Go to `Admin->Studio->Modulename->fields->Select custom fiel`d.
**2**. `check` Calculated Value then click on `Edit Formula` .
**3**. From Fields select your name field.
**4**. Then Deploy it.

Now go to your module and save your name it will appear on your custom field also.

I did not work on **Community Edition** But i can give you an idea that , you have to write a `logic hook after save` , in that hook you can write logic to copy Name to your custom field.

[For more info Logic hook click here ...](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/)